# read directory file

Tags: shell, command-line, cat

we all know that in linux directory is a special file containing the file name and the inode number of constituent files. I want to read the contents of this directory file using standard command line utility.

cat . gives an error that I cannot open a directory.
However, apparently vim can understand the content of this file using readdir probably. It displays the contents of the directory file in a formatted manner. I want the raw contents of the file. How is this possible ??

Comment: Why would you want to do this, assuming it is possible (which I don't think it is)?

Comment: just for the heck of it. It can be done using a C program but I thought of doing it using standard available tools.

Comment: You can actually read the contents of the directory(not raw contents though) using opendir and readdir commands. Here is a link to sample program http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56211033/myls.cpp

Comment: Of course you can. You'd use `find`, `ls`, `stat` or something else (or just plain globbing) for that in a shell. That's not "read the raw directory" as you say. I still don't get what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it cannot be done. I was pretty sure `dd` would do it, and then I found the following

> ‘directory’
>       Fail unless the file is a directory. Most operating systems do not allow I/O to a directory, so this flag has limited utility.

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html

So I think you have your answer there. dd supports it, as do probably a number of other utilities, but that doesn't mean linux allows it.

Comment: just out of curiosity .. why can't I read a directory file's content in the raw format. Ultimately, its a file with some text, right ??. Since, readdir (declared in dirent.h) call can do it, I guess there should be a manual way of doing this unless readdir is internally using a system call.

Comment: It may just be that the designers of the APIs couldn't think of a good reason to allow it so they disallowed it. It makes sense to me why they disallowed write. If you could write to a directory, you could corrupt the filesystem. I don't think you could make the same argument for read, but at a minimum you would make your code very tied to the particulars of the filesystem type. The way directories are stored is a feature of the filesystem type (ext2, ext3, etc.) not Linux itself. Users of the filesystem should only care about the features of the filesystem, not their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think `stat` might be the command you're looking for.

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer ?? I tried stat with printf but its not giving anything

Comment: Just use `stat` like you would use `cat`.

For example, `stat /bin`.

Comment: I have a directory testdir containing three files a, b and c. When I stat the file, I get some outpu containing access, modify time and all but it does not contain any output for files a,b and c. I presume that the directory file must contain the name of the containing files.

Comment: OK, I guess `stat` will only give you part of what you're looking for.